# How do I combine two merges from the same branch

Tags: git

I have branches `A` and `B`. I merge `B` into `A`. I commit changes to `B`. I merge `B` into `A` again. Branch `A` has now received two merges from the same branch and there are no commits on `A` in between them. This could have just been one merge that occured after the commit to `B`.

I could just discard the first merge before doing the second merge, however then I would have to resolve all of the conflicts again.

Is there a way to squash these two merges into one just to clean up the branch log? I know this is possible with regular commits.

Comment: You could reset `A` back to the commit before the first merge, and then redo the merge with the latest `B`?

Comment: Merging B onto A the second time would be a fast forward, unless you run some weird command or use an IDE that creates a merge commit anyway

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I'm confused, why would the second merge be a fast-forward?

Comment: @evolutionxbox like I said, then I have to redo the conflicts from the first merge.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov That's true but I actually got into this situation via untangling a huge mess so it didn't fast forward. So assuming that there are two separate merges, can I combine them?

Comment: You should be able to just rebase branch `A` as that will get rid of the merge-commits, leaving you with only the commits that were actually merged from branch `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a commit out of thin air and then use it to replace A

```
git commit-tree -p A~2 -p B -m "Merging B into A" A^{tree}
```

That will create a revision that has A before the two merges as one parent and B as as the other parent. It's *content* will be what you have in A. The command will print a commit ID. Check it (git log, check it out, check the contents and its history to see if it is what you want). If you like it, replace A with it:

```
git branch -f A the-id-from-commit-tree
```